# Deploying first Django project on Amazon EC2 free tier

Tags: django, amazon-ec2

Finally the time has come and I'm ready to deploy my first django project.
I'm a newbie in web development stuff and now the real fun begins.

This is a low scale site for computer jobs.
I want to start with a free tier and grow from there as need emerges.

I've read some guides regarding django project deployment but could not find all answers.
so hope some guys here could help me out:

- I've been thinking on getting Amazon EC2 free tier VPS, is this a good option?
- my local development machine runs Ubuntu, I've read that i could install 10GB Ubuntu image, do you recommend such image?
- should I go with apache or lighter web server?
- My project is hosted on bitbucket, I just need to checkout my project on my VPS right?
- What about data backups? I would like to backup my mySQL DB
- How do you recommend me serving the static files?
- I'm looking for a good tutorial on how to setup AWS with django and mysql

10x guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've been thinking on getting Amazon EC2 free tier VPS, is this a good
>   option?

If it fufills your technology requirements, ram, cpu, memory; it is a good option.

> my local development machine runs Ubuntu, I've read that i could
>   install 10GB Ubuntu image, do you recommend such image?

Might as well keep your environments the same if you can.  If you can match up versions that is another plus

> should I go with apache or lighter web server?

Either, Apache would probably be easier to deploy at this point because you don't have to worry about running it as a servicer ( using a program like like `supervisor` to manage it).
Whichever one you choose, there is an abundance of tutorials online describing how to set up django.

> My project is hosted on bitbucket, I just need to checkout my project
>   on my VPS right?

That is one way.  There are lots of ways to deploy.  I like syncing the actual files using fabric.  That way your production server doesn't need to know about your bitbucket account.  Once again, there are so many tutorials online describing deploying django.  Fabric is a great place to start.

> What about data backups? I would like to backup my mySQL DB

There exists lots of tools for this.  Plenty of premade tools and shell scripts.  I have used `automysqlbackup` and it works great http://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/

> How do you recommend me serving the static files?

Make sure the webserver serves them.  If you deploy through apache you can set up an alias to serve static files very easily.  You can come up with a collectstatic deployment scheme to put your static on s3, but for a simple site apache would be just fine

> I'm looking for a good tutorial on how to setup AWS with django and
>   mysql

Perhaps you can find a tutorial that covers this, most likely you might just find a tutorial :

1. how to setut aws with ubuntu
2. Installing django / mysql on ubuntu

Comment: thanks, do you recommend me serving MySql server off the EC2 instance?

Comment: @user2161049 i have launched low traffic sites on ec2 micro instance running apache/django/mysql and it didn't come close to exhausting the micro resources.  YOu can start small, and scale up when needed.  You can use benchmarking to test your site under load `ab` (apache benchmark) is a great little utitlity

Comment: thanks for your replay.
could you post the the steps you took to launch your site?
where do store your DB?

Comment: I think that @dm03514 has been answered your question. Make a new Question Post for new questions.